# One button click triggers another Button in Android RecyclerView

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, buttonclick

I'm currently working on a E-commerce Android app. In my recyclerview there are 13 products being populated dynamically from database. When i click the first button in the list, it also change the button text of the 11th button of the list (I coded to change the button text from Add to Remove on button click). Like wise to 2nd button click changes the text of 12th View button.
In the log i noticed both buttons have same memory value. 
Is anything i'm doing wrong?

Here is the Log generated on 3 different button clicks (1st,11th and 2nd buttons):

```
android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{9b877fd VFED..C.. ...P.... 740,120-1010,240 #7f090024 app:id/button}
android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{9b877fd VFED..C.. ...P.... 740,120-1010,240 #7f090024 app:id/button}
android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{b7dcb1b VFED..C.. ...P.... 740,120-1010,240 #7f090024 app:id/button}
```

---

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    Glide.with(mContext)
            .asBitmap()
            .load(productsList.get(position).getImage())
            .into(holder.imageView);

    holder.itemname.setText(productsList.get(position).getName());
    holder.itemprice.setText(productsList.get(position).getPrice());
    holder.itemprice_g.setText(productsList.get(position).getPrice_g());

    holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int position1 = holder.getAdapterPosition();
            if(!productsList.get(position1).isAddedTocart())
            {
                productsList.get(position1).setAddedTocart(true);
                String x = productsList.get(position1).getName().toString();
                Log.i("log",""+holder.button);
                holder.button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
                holder.button.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
                holder.button.setText("Remove");

                ((AddorRemoveCallbacks)mContext).onAddProduct();

            }
            else
            {
                productsList.get(position1).setAddedTocart(false);
                holder.button.setText("Add");
                holder.button.setPadding(12,0,0,0);
                holder.button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp, 0, 0, 0);
                ((AddorRemoveCallbacks)mContext).onRemoveProduct();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Would you please provide the code you trying and also the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `onBindViewHolder`, you should initial your `holder.button`'s state first, before the `setOnClickListener`, For example:

```
...
holder.itemname.setText(productsList.get(position).getName());
holder.itemprice.setText(productsList.get(position).getPrice());
holder.itemprice_g.setText(productsList.get(position).getPrice_g());

if (productsList.get(position1).isAddedTocart()) {
    holder.button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
    holder.button.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
    holder.button.setText("Remove");
} else {
    holder.button.setText("Add");
    holder.button.setPadding(12,0,0,0);
    holder.button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp, 0, 0, 0);
}

holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
...
```

Comment: This solved my issue.. But still technically there are some issues in my code i think. Because how come 2 different buttons get same memory space.. Have to find it. Thank you.

Comment: it's not an issue, because the views in view holders are reused, that's exactly what `RecyclerView`'s `Recycler` means, and just because the views are recycled and reused, you must set the view's state every time or you will get a unwanted outdated state :)

Answer (score 1):

Use ViewHolder with RecyclerView

https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Firstly initialize a variable in adapter holder class. 
**say, your-model-class-name product;** I think, ProductList product; Then try the following changes in onBindViewHolder.

```
     @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
holder.product = productList.get(position);
        Glide.with(mContext)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(holder.product.getImage())
                .into(holder.imageView);

        holder.itemname.setText(holder.product.getName());
        holder.itemprice.setText(holder.product.getPrice());
        holder.itemprice_g.setText(holder.product.getPrice_g());

        holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(!holder.product.isAddedTocart())
                {
                    holder.product.setAddedTocart(true);
                    String x = holder.product.getName().toString();
                    Log.i("log",""+holder.button);
                    holder.button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
                    holder.button.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
                    holder.button.setText("Remove");

                    ((AddorRemoveCallbacks)mContext).onAddProduct();

                }
                else
                {
                    holder.product.setAddedTocart(false);
                    holder.button.setText("Add");
                    holder.button.setPadding(12,0,0,0);
                    holder.button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp, 0, 0, 0);
                    ((AddorRemoveCallbacks)mContext).onRemoveProduct();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

why use   " int position1 = holder.getAdapterPosition();" 
when you already get postion in bindholder  try removing it and use default postion.

Comment: Ya, i tried that too, but the problem still exists :(